# how to identify android mobile device uniqueid in xamarin android in c#

Tags: c#, security, xamarin, xamarin.android

For my application, i need to trace the users android device **unique id**, android devices will be give to the employees by the client and when they use that device open our application and type some code. we have to check whether request came from the devices of our employees then only we will open the app. If other people have this app in their phone even though app will not open. It's a requirement which client wants, i googled it a lot found few links.
Tried this but not working

```
  public static String getDeviceAndroidID(Context context)
  {
      String android_id = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),     Secure.ANDROID_ID);
      if(android_id != null)
          return android_id;
      else
          return "";
   }
```

tried this but not getting "context . getcontentresolver()"
Need some assistance thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Try the `Android.Provider` namespace:

```
var android_id = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

Comment: If you need the id outside of an Activity you can call: `Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);`